# Not working FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK with taskAffinity

Tags: android, android-activity, taskaffinity

My application has 2 launch activities A and B. Activity B has taskAffinity="Task2".

1) Launch B from android menu, change some fields there, then press home button.

2) Launch activity A. From A, launch B with flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**. This fields are not saved. Thats the problem.

Now there is this:

1. MainTask:   Task2:B(first)
2. MainTask:A  Task2:B(first)
3. MainTask:A  Task2:B(first) -> B(second)(OnTop)

But I want this:

1. MainTask:   Task2:B(first)
2. MainTask:A  Task2:B(first)
3. MainTask:A  Task2:B(first)

Help me please. I want to apologise in advance, this is my first post and my english is not good.

**I found answer. In manifest file need to write android:launchMode="singleTop" for activity B.**

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

or

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

or

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

depending on your actual need. All of the three will achieve what you want.